# openpyxl and MS Excel: Problem with content, recover as much as we can

Tags: python, excel, ms-office, openpyxl

I have an excel with a named/excel-table (`B22:O25`) in it with header row + 3 rows of empty data-cells. I make a copy of this file, then open the copy using `openpyxl.open()`, insert 17 more rows (`ws.insert_rows(idx=23, amount=17)`), update `table.ref` (+copy formats, update autofilters etc), write a dataframe into it (`dataframe_to_rows()`).

When I save it and open it using MS Excel (Professional Plus 2016), Excel says: *We found some problem with some content in 'my file'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.*

[image]

On clicking yes, it shows:

[image]

Linked log file (`error0340...xml`) has same info: `<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)</repairedRecord>` and nothing else useful.

How do I debug this? How do I find out what was wrong/messed-up in my xlsx file? Question is more generic, where do I find some debug info from Excel?

I can post my code and example xlsx files if it helps.

---

edit: after using Open XML SDK Tools to compare the xlsx file with error and the one after being repaired by MS Excel. Ignoring the `<xml>` tag, only diff is missing `headerRowCount="1"` in repaired xlsx's `/xl/tables/table1.xml`

```
-  
- <table id="1" name="hit_ratio" displayName="hit_ratio" ref="B22:O42" headerRowCount="1" totalsRowShown="0" headerRowDxfId="17" headerRowBorderDxfId="16" tableBorderDxfId="15" totalsRowBorderDxfId="14" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
+ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
+ <table id="1" name="hit_ratio" displayName="hit_ratio" ref="B22:O42" totalsRowShown="0" headerRowDxfId="17" headerRowBorderDxfId="16" tableBorderDxfId="15" totalsRowBorderDxfId="14" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
```

Comment: You've changed a worksheet which contains a table without updating the table definition. This is a non-critical change but to avoid the warning in Excel you should update the table definition.

Comment: @CharlieClark, did you mean `table.ref`? I did update that to `B22:O42` after inserting the rows and before writing data and saving/closing the file. I also had to copy paste formats of newly added rows from existing rows. Anyway, the bigger problem is "How to debug such errors" rather than how to debug "this particular error", because I get similar issues while dealing with some images too.

Comment: The only way to debug the errors is to compare XML **very** carefully.

Comment: Already discouraging to see a bolded "*very* carefully". Anyway, looks like the only way, so could you elaborate: Compare *which* two xmls? @CharlieClark

Comment: You might have to compare three archives: source file, openpyxl, repaired. Within each archive there are lots of different XML files and the error might not be where you expect.